# Multiple select, subgroups

Tags: mysql

I have a little advise from SQL. I need to select a two groups (WHERE) in two columns. Some working 'like':

```
SELECT COUNT(WHERE Draw=1) as D1, COUNT(WHERE Draw=2) as D2 FROM SampleData
```

Exemple data table:

```
SampleData
--------------------
Id  | Draw | Element
--------------------
1   | 1    | 13
2   | 1    | 15
3   | 1    | 22
4   | 1    | 36
5   | 1    | 45
6   | 2    | 11
7   | 2    | 15
8   | 2    | 22
```

And output like this:

```
Output:

--------
D1 | D2
--------
5   | 3
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what's the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression for this:

```
 SELECT 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Draw=1 THEN 1 END) as D1, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Draw=2 THEN 1 END) as D2 
 FROM SampleData
```

mysql also supports `If()` so you could also do something like the following. Just keep in mind this isn't portable to other RDBMS's but the `CASE` version is:

```
 SELECT
     SUM(IF(Draw=1, 1, 0)) as D1,
     SUM(IF(Draw=2, 1, 0)) as D2
 FROM SampleData;
```

Also... mysql supports math on Boolean expressions so you could get really terse here:

```
 SELECT SUM(Draw=1) as D1, Sum(Draw=2) as D2 FROM SampleData;
```

Again though this is not portable to other RDBMSs like the `CASE` expression is.

Comment: Not looks very elegant but worx! :)
Many thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? (untested)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as D1 FROM SampleData WHERE Draw = 1 UNION SELECT COUNT(*) as D2 FROM SampleData WHERE Draw = 2
```

Comment: This would output two records with a single column where OP wants a single record with two columns. More worrisome though is that in the event that the number of records where `draw=1` and `draw=2` is the same this will only output a single record. In either scenario the name of the column will be `D1` which will also be difficult to discern which record is the `D1` record and which is the `D2` record.

Comment: yes, but it can't allow me to group and where for all subgroups in one place